# What is the precise meaning of arbitrary precision?

Tags: java, biginteger, arbitrary-precision

This might be a very simple question for some but I would like to know the meaning of *arbitrary precision* which appears in the first line in JavaDoc of [BigInteger](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.%3Cinit%3E%28long%29) :

> Immutable *arbitrary-precision* integers .

Comment: How does this differ from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/how-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean#12088463) 15 minutes ago?

Comment: @assylias I didn't know the meaning of arbitray precision while asking that question . Hence this question. If it turns out to be same one or the other can closed .

Comment: @assylias I think they are different questions because this one is based on terminology, the other one is based on a technical statement that he didn't understand. They have the same answer though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term *fixed precision* means that there are only a certain number of significant digits retained in the internal representation. This means that you would not be able to represent *every* integer with a magnitude greater than some threshold.

With *arbitrary precision* integers, the integers can be as large as you need ("arbitrarily large") and the library will keep all the digits down to the least significant unit. (This is obviously limited by the amount of memory in your computer.)

Answer (score 12):

It means that `BigInteger` uses as much space as is needed to save the whole value.

Take `int` as an example. It has a fixed amount of bits available. With that you can save values between `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647` (inclusive). So it is a *fixed-precision* type and not an *arbitrary-precision* type. It can not store values outside of this range.

With `BigInteger`, you don't have that problem, because once the assigned bits are not enough to store the exact value, `BigInteger` will just add some bits so it can handle the value again.

*Arbitrary* is actually not really true, because there are limits due to the fact that there is only a finite amount of memory available. That limit is not given by the `BigInteger` class but by the environment (VM/hardware/OS).