# Is there an upper bound to BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does BigInteger having no limit mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean)

The Javadoc for `BigInteger` does not define any maximum or minimum.  However, it does say:

(emphasis added)

> Immutable **arbitrary-precision** integers

Is there such a maximum, even in theory?  Or is the way `BigInteger` operates fundamentally different, such that there is in reality *no* maximum except for the amount of memory available on the computer?

Comment: In _theory_ there is no limit.

Comment: The accepted answer in that possible duplicate does not specify the theoretical limit of `BigInteger`; or, if it truly does not have one, it does not explain why.  Instead, it just says that if there *is* a maximum, it will never affect you with current memory limitations.

Comment: Its probably in base 2, so the max is (2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE in base 2.

Comment: @Ran, `BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(500500)` returned something for me.

Comment: @Ran, "returns nothing" doesn't mean anything in Java.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The number is held in an `int[]` - the maximum size of an array is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So the maximum BigInteger probably is `(2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Admittedly, this is implementation dependent, not part of the specification.

---

In Java 8, some information was added to [the BigInteger javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), giving a minimum supported range and the actual limit of the current implementation:

> `BigInteger` must support values in the range `-2`<sup>`Integer.MAX_VALUE`</sup> (exclusive) to `+2`<sup>`Integer.MAX_VALUE`</sup> (exclusive) and may support values outside of that range.
>
> Implementation note: `BigInteger` constructors and operations throw `ArithmeticException` when the result is out of the supported range of `-2`<sup>`Integer.MAX_VALUE`</sup> (exclusive) to `+2`<sup>`Integer.MAX_VALUE`</sup> (exclusive).

Comment: As the values are used as unsigned `int` values, the maximum is more like `(2^32)^Integer.MAX_VALUE * 10^Integer.MAX_VALUE` as it can be scaled as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Are you sure there is a scale for BigInteger? (there is one for BigDecimal).

Comment: Since integer MAX_VALUE is approx 2^31, the maximal value can't be kept in 32-bit computer memory :) So the memory is the limit.

Comment: @SuzanCioc You could store an array of 2^32 integers on a 64 bits machine though (assuming you have enough RAM).

Comment: @assylias Good point. You can also store a `new int[2^31-1]` in a 64-bit JVM. Its about 8 GB which costs about $40.

Comment: @assylias I do not understand how you get to the calculation  `(2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE` . Eg:  I have a `int[]` that can save maximum `5` `int`s . Each `int` can have a maximum value of `2^4`. Then the array with maximum values saved in it will look like `{16,16,16,16,16}`. If it is represented in the background by `BigInteger` as `1616161616` then how this number `which is supposed to be (MAX_NUMBER)` is equivalent to `(2^4)^5` ? Or I am understanding it completely wrong.

Comment: What I understood is that `2^32` is the maximum `unsigned int` value that we can save at a single place in the array. The array can have a length of maximum `2^32` or `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE` . Then how `(2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE` ?

Comment: @Ankit each` int` can take 2^32 values. An array of `int` can hold up to 2^32 `int`s. That array can therefore represent up to 2^32 (the number of positions in the array) ^ (2^32) (the number of values that each position can have).

Comment: @assylias This is where I am getting confused `ARRAY can represent UPTO`. In my example an array can represent max `1616161616`. and it is not equal to max we will get by `5 (number of positions in the array) ^ 16 (number the number of values that each position can have)`.

Comment: @Ankit To make it simple, imagine your array has 2 positions, and each positions can have 3 values, the possible values are (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2, 2), or a total of 3^2 = 9 combinations. So you could use that to represent numbers from 0 to 8 (the fact that the largest combination is (2,2) does not mean that the largest number is 22).

Comment: @assylias, would you please clarify: 1.  `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the max size of a **`Byte` array on a 32-bit machine**, isn't it? 2. If so,  the array can therefore represent up to (assuming we get the whole RAM) `Byte.MAX_VALUE (the number of values that each position can have) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE` (the number of positions in the array)?

Comment: 1. Integer.MAX_VALUE is the maximum size of arrays in general in Java (whether it's an `int[]` or a `byte[]` and whether the JVM is 32 or 64 bits. 2. I don't understand why you are referring to bytes - BigIntegers are stored in an `int[]`.

Comment: `(2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE` are so many numbers, I hope never need to use it

Comment: All in all, its approximately `18GB` or somewhat more than that (below 19GB).

Comment: @assylias What is stopping them to implement it using a `LinkedList`?

Comment: wouldn't it be (Integer.MAX_VALUE)^(Integer.MAX_VALUE)? which would be smaller than what you're suggesting for most implementations where the max value is 2147483647, not 4294967295

Comment: @DavidBandel Possibly, but you could also use the array to hold the unsigned value and have the sign in a separate field. It seems to be the case for [the reference implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l124).

Answer (score 23):

> BigInteger would only be used if you know it will not be a decimal and
>   there is a possibility of the long data type not being large enough.
>   BigInteger has no cap on its max size (as large as the RAM on the
>   computer can hold).

From [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Math#BigInteger).

It is implemented using an `int[]`:

```
  110       /**
  111        * The magnitude of this BigInteger, in <i>big-endian</i> order: the
  112        * zeroth element of this array is the most-significant int of the
  113        * magnitude.  The magnitude must be "minimal" in that the most-significant
  114        * int ({@code mag[0]}) must be non-zero.  This is necessary to
  115        * ensure that there is exactly one representation for each BigInteger
  116        * value.  Note that this implies that the BigInteger zero has a
  117        * zero-length mag array.
  118        */
  119       final int[] mag;
```

From [the source](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html)

From the Wikipedia article [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic):

> Several modern programming languages have built-in support for
>   bignums, and others have libraries available for arbitrary-precision
>   integer and floating-point math. Rather than store values as a fixed
>   number of binary bits related to the size of the processor register,
>   these implementations typically use variable-length arrays of digits.

Answer (score 14):

The first maximum you would hit is the length of a String which is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 digits.  It's much smaller than the maximum of a BigInteger but IMHO it loses much of its value if it can't be printed.

Comment: In full fairness, you'd just need more logic to print it.

Comment: If its ok to use multiple Strings you could use multiple BigIntegers as well. ;)

Comment: True, but that would cause much more complications in your code than just the print routine.