# FacebookID String to BigInt Java and Parse

Tags: java, android, string, facebook, bigint

I am building an app which utilizes the Parse back-end. As part of my user object I want to directly use the FacebookID as my UserID, but I want to convert it to a BigInt instead of a string.

I used the following code, but when I check the data in Parse the value is slightly off.

"user" is a GraphUser object which I have declared above.

```
String iDString = user.getId();
BigInteger iD = new BigInteger(iDString);
currentUser.put("faceID", iD);
```

When I check the data in Parse I get the following:

Original ID in string format (* are used to cover digits):

```
************27645
```

BigInt ID:

```
************27644
```

Does anyone know why the last digit is 1 less than the digit above? May it have something to with the sign of the BigInt?

Comment: Hard to tell without actual values but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693273/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-biginteger) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which is your problem due to the lack of information in your post.

This simple case works very well for me though:

```
String iDString = "99999999999997645";
BigInteger iD = new BigInteger(iDString);
System.out.println(iD.toString());
```

The printed number is exactly the same of the iDString "number".

Comment: You're right, I just tested it client side and the values are completely the same. When it is being saved to Parse the value is changing. That is so strange.