# Long vs BigInteger

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger

I understand that both `java.lang.Long` and `java.math.BigInteger`can hold very large natural numbers.

I also know Long's max value, but what is the max value for BigInteger?

And aside from capacity, would BigInteger ever perform better when working with generally large integers that still fall in Long's range?

### Question

Is the only consideration: is my value too large for Long?

Comment: BigInteger is capable of holding far bigger numbers than Long. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693273/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-biginteger

Comment: If Long is enough, use Long. If not, use BigInteger.

Comment: Same way you choose between any numeric types.  Is it possible for the value in question to exceed the size of a particular type?  If so, use a larger type.

Comment: @Samha awesome rewrite - thank you!

Comment: @David I wouldn't say it's the case with "any numeric type". Take `Double` and `BigDecimal`. You would use `BigDecimal` if precision was critical, even though value range of `Double` is enough.

Answer (score 73):

BigInteger is capable of holding far bigger numbers than Long. BigInteger seems capable of holding (2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE, though that depends on the implementation (and, even if truly unbounded in the implementation, there will eventually be a physical resource limit) [See explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693273/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-biginteger).

The range of `Long` is [-9,223,372,036,854,775,808, +9,223,372,036,854,775,807].

Long will perform better than BigInteger so it really depends on what the size of your values will be. If they would all fall under Long's max value, it makes no sense not to use Long. If any would be bigger than the Long max value, you pretty much have to use BigInteger.

Comment: Note that `(2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE` is implementation-dependent. Theoretically BigInteger has no max value.

Comment: So, this is the only consideration then: is my value too large for Long?

Comment: @FritzDuchardt As far as I can see, yes. Long will definitely be better performing than BigInteger so size of your values is really the determining factor.