# What variable type can I use to hold huge numbers in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a class similar to BigInteger for Java in Kotlin to hold very large numbers? Eg: 100 Digits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigInteger in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287466/biginteger-in-kotlin)

Comment: No! I wanna know if there is a equivalent for BigInteger natively in kotlin instead of mixing java classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no such class in the official Kotlin standard library other than Java's BigInteger. You might be able to use third-party libraries such as [kotlin-multiplatform-bignum](https://github.com/ionspin/kotlin-multiplatform-bignum) or [kt-math](https://github.com/gciatto/kt-math), as long as you're ok with their licence conditions and be aware that both of them may change in future, and that neither of them is likely to be as fast as Java's BigInteger.