# Quick question, why is my exponents capped?

Tags: java, exponent

```
public static void main(String[] args){

int res = (int)Math.pow(2017, 202);

System.out.println(res);
}
```

This outputs 2147483647

Which is obviously wrong and if i type in other exponents the output remains the same.
How do i remove this cap and what is causing it?

Comment: Simply use `BigInteger`: `BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(2017).pow(202)`

Comment: If you are doing that calculation for some kind of coding / math quiz / question then chances are that actually calculating the power is not needed at all, e.g. if you `mod` afterwards

Answer (score 1):

To remove the cap, use a different datatype.

`int` is capped at 2^31-1, `long` is capped at 2^63-1, but AFAIK BigInteger is not capped:

```
BigInteger res = new BigInteger("2017").pow(202)
```

Don't use it for normal calculations, however, since it's much slower.

Comment: [`BigInteger` is capped, but not enforced by the specs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12693273/5515060)

Comment: [Here's what `Math.pow(2017, 202)` is.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2017%5E202)