# Getting Numberformat exception with unknown source. How to fix this

Tags: java, exception

How to fix this issue?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

I am doing some example problem and my code is working fine for the first string and digit. (Commented one)

But when change the new string and digit (Current one) I am getting this error :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "299858953917872714814599237991174513476623756395992135212546127959342974628712329595771672911914471"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at com.codejam.q1.problems.maxResult.removeDigit(maxResult.java:21)
    at com.codejam.q1.problems.maxResult.main(maxResult.java:10)
```

Here is my code. Anywhere I am missing something ?

```java
public class maxResult {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String str = "1231";
        String str = "2998589353917872714814599237991174513476623756395992135212546127959342974628712329595771672911914471";
        //char digit = '1';
        char digit = '3';
        System.out.println(removeDigit(str,digit));
    }
    
    public static String removeDigit(String number, char digit) {
        long result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<number.length(); i++) {
            char num = number.charAt(i);
            if(num == digit) {
                String myStr = number.substring(0, i) + number.substring(i + 1); 
                try{
                    long myNum = Long.parseLong(myStr);  
                    if(myNum > result) {
                        result = myNum;
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }
        String s = String.valueOf(result);  
        return s;
    }
}
```

Even though I change `int` to `long` but no change in result.

Comment: If you are trying to remove every occurrence of the digit `3` from `str`, then you can simply do: `str.replaceAll("3", "");` Or did I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Comment: Alternatively, consider using class [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) Refer to this SO question: [Is there an upper bound to BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693273/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-biginteger)

Answer (score 1):

The number is too long for a long. Longs go from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,808.

Try doing this :

```
public static String removeDigit(String number, char digit) {
    double temp = 0;
    String result="";
    for(int i = 0; i<number.length(); i++) {
        char num = number.charAt(i);
        if(num == digit) {
            String myStr = number.substring(0, i) + number.substring(i + 1); 
            try{
                double myNum = Double.parseDouble(myStr);  
                if(myNum > temp) {
                    temp = myNum;
                    result=myStr;
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what should I do here ?

Comment: I am converting string to long/int and then comaparing with result. I am returning the maximum value after removing the digit.

Comment: what are you trying to do when comparing the value? do you just want the biggest value of the long ??

Comment: Do you want to remove only the first occurrence of that number then ?

Comment: In loop I am removing all the occurence of number one by one and then comparing with result and getting the maxium one.

Comment: So you want to remove only one number and keep the biggest answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your number is too big for a long value. The maximum long value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. You can use BigInteger, which essentially has no limit.

**Using `long`**

```
long result = 0;
// ...
long myNum = Long.parseLong(myStr);  
if(myNum > result) {
    result = myNum;
}
// ...
String s = String.valueOf(result);  
return s;
```

**Using `BigInteger`**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
// ...
BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
// ...
BigInteger myNum = new BigInteger(myStr);
result = myNum.max(result);
// ...
return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you get is that you are exceeding the limit of the `int` and the `long`. Let us see the limits of some number storing types and then use the best one:

| Type | Size | Value | Exceeds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int | 32 bit | -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 | Yes |
| long | 64 bit | -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 | Yes |
| float | 32 bit | 3.40282347 x 1038 to 1.40239846 x 10-45 | Yes |
| double | 64 bit | 1.7976931348623157 x 10308 to 4.9406564584124654 x 10-324 | Yes |
| **BigInteger** | **32 bit** | **2^64billion** | **No** |

Here, we find that **`BigInteger`** is the class we need to use. So, instead of using a `long` or `int` for it, use **`BigInteger`**. To know more about BigInteger, visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/).

Also to know how to use a big integers refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72073983/17133283)

Comment: You evidently copied a source that used superscripted exponents but removed the superscripting, giving results which are quite wrong. Also BigInteger isn't infinite; its limit is about 2^64billion, a number which in decimal has about 19billion digits, which is _very_ big but finite.

Comment: Ok. @dave_thompson_085. I didnt know the vlue so i wrote infinite. U can edit and give the value there

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigDecimal instead of long.

```
public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //String str = "1231";
            String str = "2998589353917872714814599237991174513476623756395992135212546127959342974628712329595771672911914471";
            //char digit = '1';
            char digit = '3';
            System.out.println(removeDigit(str,digit));
        }

        public static BigDecimal removeDigit(String number, char digit) {
            BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            for(int i = 0; i<number.length(); i++) {
                char num = number.charAt(i);
                if(num == digit) {
                    String myStr = number.substring(0, i) + number.substring(i + 1);
                    try{
                        BigDecimal myNum = new BigDecimal(myStr);
                        if(myNum.compareTo(result)>0) {
                            result = myNum;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```