# Storing data with large input

Tags: storage, large-data

There is a problem in a competitive programming site(hackerrank) in which the input number is of the range 10^18.So,is it possible to store (10^18) in java?If yes then which data type should be used?

Answer (score 1):

For some easy HackerRank problems, **BigInteger** or **BigDecimal** do work for extremely large inputs,but they usually don't work in moderate/difficult problems as they tend to reduce performance & a high number of test-cases of extremely large inputs can  cause a timeout.

> In such cases,you will need go for different storage techniques e.g. an array of  **int**,each element of the array representing a digit of the large input. You will then need to do digit-based arithmetic on the array for your computations.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(10000)
```

No real need not be careful, as the BigInteger.valueOf(long) method will give you a compilation error if you try to write a literal that exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE. Furthermore, it's easy to construct a BigInteger much greater, say [BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(10000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean)