# I wrote this program to find if a given input is power of 2 , this program is not running for very large number such as 10^18 or so. what should i do

Tags: java, int

This is a program to check if an input is power of 2 or not. This program is running fine for inputs up to 8 digits but when I am giving input like 10<sup>18</sup>, it is not working, What should I do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class search {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            //to take how many inputs are there
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int k ;
            k = sc.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0 ;i<k;i++){
            // input number n
            long  n ;


            n = sc.nextInt();

            if ((n > 0) && ((n & (n - 1)) == 0)){
                System.out.println("YES");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that 10<sup>18</sup> is out of range of Java `int`, which stores numbers up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or roughly 2*10<sup>9</sup>. You can expand the range of your program by using `long` in place of `int` to accept numbers up to 9*10<sup>18</sup>, or to make it accept virtually unlimited range by using [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(numericString);
BigInteger test = n.and(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
if (test.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your input number as `String` then use `BigInteger` class to avoid limit surpassing problem,

```
BigInteger inputNumber = new BigInteger(inputString);
```

Also, refer [What does BigInteger having no limit mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean)  to know more about `BigInteger` limits.

Answer (score 0):

If the `long` number range is enough, you can just change

```
n = sc.nextInt();
```

to

```
n = sc.nextLong();
```

At the moment, `n` is only set to an integer and therefore limited to the `int` number range.

Answer (score 0):

Better Use Class BigInteger it implement `Serializable`, `Comparable<BigInteger>` .`BigInteger` provides operations for modular arithmetic, GCD calculation, primality testing, prime generation, bit manipulation, and a few other miscellaneous operations.

```
input="Number"
BigInteger number = new BigInteger(input);
//Do your stuff
```

Happy to help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take the input in long:

```js
 k = sc.nextLong();
```