# How can I keep 1 million digit in Java?

Tags: string, compiler-errors, variable-assignment, biginteger, digit

My question is that, I want to multiply 2 number which has 1 million digit. When I tried to assign 1 million number to BigInteger, Compiler is giving to me error. The error is that:"constant string too long".

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean

Comment: you have a one-million digit long String representing a number? What kind of calculation you're doing? I seem to be able to create a BigInteger instance with one million digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigInteger` is indeed the way to store such large integers, although hundreds or a few thousands of digits are more typical use cases. However, Java class files have limitations that won't allow hard coding a literal number that large.

Instead, store the number in a file and read it at runtime. If the file contains a textual representation in decimal, hexadecimal, or some other base, you can [read it into a `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/3474) and pass it to [the `BigInteger` constructor.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-) If the file contains the raw bits, [load it to a `byte[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-) and use a [different constructor.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-)