# How to show this

Tags: android

I have a question. I want to make a app for mind reader. First i want to give 1 to 100 number and ask the user to think in mind a number.on next i want to display 1 to 50 and two button yes,no.  When click on yes it shows 1 to 25 and on no it shows 50 to 75 and so on.

Comment: why only millions? why not billions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I keep 1 million digit in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081432/how-can-i-keep-1-million-digit-in-java)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081432/how-can-i-keep-1-million-digit-in-java

Comment: Please tell me in details.

Comment: Please answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Biginteger and BigDecimal instead of int and decimal

```
BigInteger a=new BigInteger(valueA);
BigInteger b=new BigInteger(valueB);
BigInteger c=a.multiply(b);
```

Comment: Please Answer MY question ASAP.