# converting string to Integer val

Tags: java

if my String contains 100 digits or 900 digits how can i parse it to Integer value Java.

```
public static void main(String...args){
    long answer1=-1,answer2=-1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m = sc.nextInt();//length
    int s = sc.nextInt();//sum
    String startNmbr="1",endNmbr="9";
    int startRange=1,endRange=9;
    for(int i=1;i<m;i++){
        startNmbr+="0";endNmbr+="9";endRange+=9;
    }
    long end = Long.parseLong(endNmbr);
    for(long start=Long.parseLong(startNmbr);start<=end;start++){
        if(answer1==-1 && countNmbr(start)==s){
            answer1=start;
        }
        if(answer1!=-1 && countNmbr(start)==s){
            answer2=start;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(answer1+" "+answer2);
}
public static int countNmbr(long a){
    int answer=0;
    String str = a+"";
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        answer+=(str.charAt(i)-'0');
    }
    return answer;
}
```

My input was 100,100;
I must return the min and max values that their length==m and sum == s;

Comment: You can't parse to a regular integer, but maybe `BigInteger` would work.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
 at C489.main(C489.java:21)
C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Comment: there my exception on line 21

Comment: That number is far too large to fit into a `long`, that's why you get the exception. Use `BigInteger` as Tim already mentioned.

Comment: And why don't you use `BigInteger` for that? `Long` is too small for a number with 100 digits

Comment: Why down vote ? Question is perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Integer's `MAX_VALUE` is 2,147,483,647. Which is 10 digits.

You can use [BigInteger - No Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean), but it depends on your memory and system architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse you 900 digits of number into Integer because theoretically, Integer has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647
([see java docs on Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html))

[Big Integer however](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) will fulfill your use case since theoretically it has the range of -2^Integer.MAX_VALUE(2,147,483,647) to +2^Integer.MAX_VALUE(2,147,483,647).

In your code you can just parse the string like this :

```java
BigInteger end = new BigInteger(endNmbr);
```

and change all long type into BigInteger and you'll good to go.