# How to power up a huge number in java?

Tags: java, pow

I looking for a way to power up a number and finding mod, 
something like this in python 
`pow(x, y, z)`
for example x ^ y % z  
x is about 3 digits, y is about 450 digits, and z is about 400 digits
thanks in advance

Comment: Check the `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` classes.

Comment: I already tried that , second value is very huge and I can't find mod

Comment: "I can't find mod" .. then you didn't even look. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod-java.math.BigInteger-

Comment: You want [BigInteger.modPow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,java.math.BigInteger%29).  As in, `result = x.modPow(y, z);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you are looking for:    `public BigInteger modPow(BigInteger exponent,BigInteger m)`

Usage:

```
BigInteger base= new BigInteger("111");
BigInteger exponent= new BigInteger(yourExponent);
BigInteger m= new BigInteger(yourM);
System.out.println(base.modPow(exponent,m));
```

For limitations of BigInteger see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean)