# NumberFormatException For input String "11111000000000000000"

Tags: java, scala

I attempted the following command in **Scala** and get a `NumberFormatException`, but I am not sure why. It may be something elementary, but I would certainly appreciate an extra set of eyes. Thank you so much!

"11111000000000000000".toLong

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "11111000000000000000"   at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>   at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)   at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:276)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:30)
>   ... 33 elided

Comment: What is `long` max value?

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The method

```
Long.parseLong(String s)
```

parses the string argument as a `signed decimal long` (uses radix of 10). `11111000000000000000`, when treated as a base 10 number is larger than the maximum value of `Long`, which is why the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` is being thrown.

Chances are you're looking for

```
Long.parseLong("11111000000000000000", 2)
```

which treats the number as binary (base 2).

Otherwise you may want to check out [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)  which can handle arbitrary precision integers.

Answer (score 3):

```
 9223372036854775807 // maximum value of Long
11111000000000000000 // your value
```

Notice something?

Comment: Can questions be answered with another question?

Comment: @VinceEmigh It is OK as long it is not main part of the answer, so I would say that in this case everything is fine.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, evidently, the answer is "yes"?

Comment: It seems to me that +AtomHeartFather found a better way to answer the question in a clear way. He even spotted a potential misunderstanding (radix) and addressed it.

Answer (score 2):

long range for 64bit

`–9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to

```
 9 ,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

or use **BigInteger**
ex:
Using the constructor

```
String val="111110000000000000000"

BigInteger(String val)
```

Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger.

reference:
[BigInteger or not BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776400/biginteger-or-not-biginteger)

[String to BigInteger java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717240/string-to-biginteger-java)